# Manutenção de pacotes off-line do Linux Debian

Tags: linux

Devido a problemas de internet onde estou morando, preciso manter um mecanismo para atualizar minhas instalações linux sem depender sempre da internet.

No caso preciso baixar os pacotes para um pequeno microservidor que montei em um NanoPI com HD de 1Tb e assim quando estiver em meu laboratório eu posso atualizar as demais máquinas.

Tentei com o Kyrix, mas está muito antigo, depois descobri o apt-offline, mas este eu preciso da internet para instala-lo.

Como devo proceder para fazer tais manutenções?